# Android indexoutofboundsexception

Tags: c#, java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

helo everyone i working Regex. i have indexoutofboundsexception 
this is a my source

```
public String ExtractYoutubeURLFromHTML(String html) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{

     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(this.extractionExpression);


     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);

     List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
     while(matcher.find()){
         matches.add(matcher.group());
     }


    String vid0 = matches.get(0).toString();


    vid0 = vid0.replace ("\\\\u0026", "&");
    vid0 = vid0.replace ("\\\\\\", "");


    vid0=URLDecoder.decode(vid0,"UTF-8");



    return vid0;

}
```

i debuged and i have indexoutofboundsexception invalid index exception

error is in this part of code

```
 List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
     while(matcher.find()){
         matches.add(matcher.group());
     }


    String vid0 = matches.get(0).toString();
```

also i have woring code in C# and i want to rewrite C# code in java Code
this is a working code in C#

```
public string ExtractYoutubeURLFromHTML(string html)
    {
        Regex rx = new Regex (this.extractionExpression);


        var video = rx.Matches (html);

        var vid0 = video [0].ToString ();

        vid0 = vid0.Replace ("\\\\u0026", "&");
        vid0 = vid0.Replace ("\\\\\\", "");

        vid0 = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode (vid0);


        return vid0;

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `matches.get(0)` exist in the context of your code?

Comment: @txtechhelp yes i am sure

Comment: Check your List, and if no item exists in it, skip the rest, `String vid0 = matches.get(0).toString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this one :

```
String vid0 = matches.get(0).toString();
```

by

```
if(matches.size() > 0){

    String vid0 = matches.get(0).toString();

} else {

    return ""   // or you can also return null;

}
```

Comment: i changed it but now i have nullpointexception.i updated my code

Comment: Please edit your code . i have edit my answer please refer again and replace your code by new one.

Comment: i changed my code like this  if(matches.size() > 0){
    vid0    = matches.get(0).toString();
   }
   else
   {
    return html ;
   }

Answer (score 1):

If `matches` is empty then `matches.get(0).toString();` will give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Better check like

```
if(matches.size()>0)
  String vid0 = matches.get(0).toString();
```